# How to check if an IP is in the Database

Tags: php, sql

How do I check if an ip is in the database?

I'm creating a little voting system and right now people can vote more than once.

So i put thier Ip in the database and if its already in the database dont want it to allow the upvote. I get the ips in the database using:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `ip` FROM `voted`") or die(mysql_error());
```

I just don't know how to check if the ip that person is voting with is already entered.

Comment: IP is a good start, but what about dynamic IP addressing?

Comment: put a cookie in addition to ip check

Comment: Please don't use the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Forgot to mention Im also pretty new to PHP and Mysql. So I dont know what dynamic ip addressing is and i dont know how to use cookies in php

Comment: dynamic IP addressing means that the IP addresses change, meaning you cannot associate a specific user with a single fixed IP address, at least not reliably. Dynamic IPs are not language specific, but rather a part of networking.

Comment: This sounds *a lot* like you want to check the current user visiting the page against a list of IP addresses already in the database. You should be more specific if you needed help creating the query rather than determining the current client's IP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at the `WHERE` clause in MySQL:

http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlwhere.php

```
$ip = mysql_real_escape_string([the IP address]);
$q = mysql_query("SELECT `ip` FROM `voted` WHERE `ip`= '$ip'");
if(mysql_num_rows($q) > 0){
    // They already are in the database
}
```

Remember-- *sanitize your inputs*. Personally, I would use parameters and bindings, but if you are going plain-vanilla MySQL then just use the escaping function. But remember, the `mysql_` functions are being deprecated, so I would avoid them if possible. (See [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php))

Comment: Well, depending on how he gets the IP address, it could be. For example, if he is retrieving the IP from a POST variable, it could be. He never specified. *ALWAYS* sanitize everything in the query. It helps when you don't necessarily know if something can be injected or not.

Comment: Good catch, knittl-- I'm used to PDO and not including quotes when binding ;)

Comment: Andrew: I fixed your query. Using `mysql_real_escape_string` for values not enclosed in quotation marks has no benefit at all. (Apart from a syntax error in this very example)

Comment: knittl: See my comment above-- I'm psychic and responded before you commented ;)

Comment: Another thing people usually forget to sanitise is the UA or X-Forwarded-For, which can also be any arbitrary string.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you already have a way to get the IP address (since you're inserting them into the database).  So it's a matter of a WHERE clause to validate:

```
$check = mysql_query("SELECT `ip` FROM `voted` WHERE `ip` = '$theIP'")...
```

Then check if you get any results back. If you do, then refuse the vote.

Note, however, that validating entirely based on IP addresses will give you a lot of false negatives.

Answer (score 0):

I should use something like:

```
SELECT count(*) INTO counter from `voted` WHERE ip = '0.0.0.0'
```

and in your php code you'll check if counter is more than 0.

Comment: Remember to sanitize user data!

Answer (score 0):

If your going to stick with mysql_* then something like [Andrew M](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11730165/881551) advised will work fine. Like he and others suggest though, consider the PDO route (below) if you're just starting to learn PHP

**MySQL**

```
<?php
if (!$qry = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(*) AS `daCount` FROM `voted` WHERE `ip` = '".mysql_escape_string($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])."'")) {
    die('Whamm PoW! Oops, we made a boo boo!');
}

list($check) = mysql_fetch_row($qry);
if ($check > 0) {
    echo 'Thanks but you already voted!';
}
else {
    echo 'Please make your vote: Yes or No?';
}
```

**PDO**

```
<?php
try { // to connect to database
    $db = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=testdb;charset=UTF-8', 'username', 'password', array(
        PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
        PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
    ));
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('Bazinga! Oops, we made a boo boo!');
}

try { // to execute query and stuff
    $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT `ip` FROM `voted` WHERE `ip`=?');
    $stmt->execute(array($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']));
    $row_count = $stmt->rowCount();
    if ($row_count > 0) {
        echo 'Thanks but you already voted!';
    }
    else {
        echo 'Please make your vote: Yes or No?';
    }

} catch(PDOException $e) {
    die('Kaboom! Oops, we made a boo boo!');
}
```